# Power Query column1 is not found when sorting any column

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I have a power query structure in Excel 2016 to fetch over 10000 json files in a folder. the data retrieving works just fine but when I sort any column I get this error:

```
Expression.Error: The column 'Column1' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Column1
```

I have no idea where this is coming from since I'm not using 'Column1' in my query. and it was working when there were around 4000 files in that folder.

any Idea on where to look for??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the **MCode** in the `Advanced Editor`

Comment: @ron-rosenfeld I did... and I don't have Column1 in the advanced editor either.

Comment: It's most likely something in your code, but cannot tell from the information you have provided.

Comment: I found out where the error was coming from... some of my JSONs were empty resulting the whole query to return the same error. ... but I just was able to see the error in query editor when I sorted columns...

Comment: Hopefully, with all those files, you'll be able to modify your code to check for an empty JSON.